# CASE statement is not working with "IN"

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below SQL query returns results.

```
declare @flag bit = 0

select * 
from file_table fd 
where fd.person_id = case @flag 
                        when 0 then 10349196 
                        else fd.person_id 
                     end
```

But I want to change the above query to include two person_ids as below.

```
declare @flag bit = 0
declare @person_ids varchar(100) = '(1001,1002)'

select * 
from file_table fd 
where fd.person_id in case @flag 
                          when 0 then @person_ids 
                          else fd.person_id 
                      end
```

But this query throws error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case'

Can anyone help me fix this issue? My intention is that I want to include two person ids (as shown in the second query) inside the case statement.

Comment: The answer given is basically how you get around the syntax error, but you will still have errors with this because SQL will not parse the text in your variable... You need to use dynamic SQL if you wish to do something like this with non-static values. Alternatively, use two separate variables and have `IN (@var1, @var2)`

Comment: This will get around syntax error. But doesn't return any result sets though the table have entries for these two person ids. Any idea why?

Comment: Case expression, not case statement. (Since it returns a value!!!)

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @flag bit = 0
declare @person_ids varchar(100) = '(1001,1002)'

select * 
from file_table fd 
where fd.person_id in (select 
                           case @flag when 0 then @person_ids 
                                      else fd.person_id 
                           end)
```

Comment: This will get around syntax error. But doesn't return any result sets though the table have entries for these two person ids. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OR` as the below:

```
declare @flag bit = 0
declare @person_ids varchar(100) = ',1001,1002,' -- You need ',' at beginning and end

select * 
from file_table fd 
where 
    @flag  != 0 OR
    @person_ids LIKE '%,' + fd.person_id + ',%' -- Type of fd.person_id must be varchar. 
                                                -- If not Convert to varchar.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @flag bit =0
--declare @person_ids varchar(100) = '(1001,1002)'

--drop table #person_ids
create table #person_ids (name varchar(30))
insert into #person_ids   values('1001')
insert into #person_ids   values('1002')

 select * from file_table fd ,#person_ids where fd.person_id in  
(select case  when @flag=0 then   name  else fd.person_id end)

drop table #person_ids
```

Comment: This is little bit heavy but it will solve your problem try and confirm

Answer (score 0):

Your case statement will not work if the `person_id` column contains integer value. Try with the below script .

```
DECLARE @flag bit = 0
DECLRAE @person_ids varchar(100) = '1,2'

;WITH cte_1
AS
(SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS SplitValues
FROM
(SELECT CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(@person_ids,',','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML)AS x)t
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n))
SELECT *
FROM file_table  c
 LEFT JOIN cte_1 c1 ON c.person_id=c1.SplitValues
WHERE c.person_id=CASE  WHEN  @flag=0 THEN  c1.SplitValues ELSE c.person_id END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bellow query

```
declare @flag bit = 0
select *  from file_table fd 
where fd.person_id = case @flag when 1 then  fd.person_id end 
OR fd.person_id IN(1001,1002)
```

You may need proper format data in 'IN'